# How to handle downloadable assets in MvvmCross

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I have an app that synchronises content with a web server so that the app ends up with an offline and cut down version of the server based web pages. All text and html is stored in a SQLite database but what is the best approach for handling file assets? In my case this is a mix of image and audio files.

The synchronisation is all set up in the core project and my Touch project has a Content directory set up for storing the assets and my intention had been to have a similar setup for Droid. I could pass the list of files needed to the UI projects and download them from there but that seems wrong.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that I would create a Service in Mvx which the ViewModels you create use for getting the external assets. Take for instance the [Daily Dilbert Tutorial](https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross-Tutorials/blob/master/DailyDilbert). You could consider the daily comics as being very similar to your external assets, where the [DilbertService](https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross-Tutorials/blob/master/DailyDilbert/DailyDilbert.Core/Services/DilbertService.cs) is used to get all the comics and presents them in a `List`. However your list could be a list of files located on the SDcard or where you decide to store your files.

Comment: Is there a standard way of storing files that is then accessible for both Droid and Touch?

Comment: There is the File plugin: https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/tree/v3/Plugins/Cirrious/File